# How to convert string to date type in MarkLogic?

Tags: javascript, marklogic, data-conversion

I am currently having some challenge in converting `String` data type to `Date` type. I used the MarkLogic JavaScript function `xdmp.parseDateTime`, but I am always getting the error below:

**Scenario:** Convert "2013-04-21" (string) to 2013-04-21 (date type)

**Code:**

```
let targetDateString = "2013-04-21";
let targetDate = new Date();

targetDate = xdmp.parseDateTime("[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]", 
xs.date(targetDate));
```

**Error Info:**

> XDMP-ARGTYPE: xdmp.parseDateTime("[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]", xs.date("2013-04-21")) -- arg2 is not of type String

Am I using the right MarkLogic function, supplying the right parameters to it?
Or is there a better way to do it?

And how do I cast a date back to a string data type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`xs.date("2013-04-21")` is the xquery date constructor (ported to JS), taking a string and returning an xs:date. `xs.dateTime("2013-04-21T00:00:00")` would get you an xs:dateTime.

`xdmp.parseDateTime` can turn a string to xs:dateTime from more formats, the second term is a string: `xdmp.parseDateTime("[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]", targetDateString)`

See https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.parseDateTime

Converting back to a string is just `fn.string(yourdate)`

Answer (score 3):

you can directly use the constructor of `date` class.

```
var d = new Date("2013-04-21");
console.log(d);
```

you can even use it with different formats, [Ref](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp).